# Two winforms one modal dialog situation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have two open winforms, say that winform1 gets a modal dialog, this means that all forms(winform1 and winform2) will be "disabled". If we minimize all forms and then bring up winform1, then the modal dialog will be shown above it. If we again minimize all the forms but this time brings up winform2, it will look like the finform2 is ready to be used while its really disabled like winform1.

What I need is to clearly show that the modal dialog needs to be handled before using winform2 again.

Is there anything built in to handle this or am I on my own here?

Comment: It's possible but tricky. Is the modal dialog one that you create (e.g. `modalForm = new Form();`), or could it be a `MessageBox`?

Comment: The modalForm is a regular created winform (modalForm=newForm();)

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer based on that. (For MessageBox, it may not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `winform2.Activated` event handler, call this:

```
    static void FocusModalForm()
    {
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            if (form.Modal)
            {
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                form.BringToFront();
            }
    }
```

e.g.

```
   Form f2 = new Form();
   f2.Activated += (_, __) => FocusModalForm();
   f2.Show();
```

You may need to do the same thing for `winform1`'s `Activated` event. It depends how `winform2` gets created. Just try it and if you find that `winform1` (or any other nonmodal form) is still able to get in front of the modal form, just call `FocusModalForm()` from its `Activated` event.

I tried this in Windows 7. I tried hiding all windows (click the Show Desktop button on the taskbar) and then selecting form2 directly from the taskbar, and I also tried just selecting form2 from the taskbar without hiding all windows. Form3 always stayed on top.

Comment: I tried this and it looks great. I did however not use a static method but a regular one but I see the point in using a static method for this if it is to be used for multiple forms. I have hover not tried how regular messagebox will work. Thanks alot!

Comment: If a regular MessageBox.Show is used, then this solution is not working.

Comment: @SnowJim: I know, that's why I asked you how you created the form. If you want it to work with MessageBox.Show.... there's more work to do. (In other words, I don't know why it doesn't work) :)

Comment: If I dont use MessageBox.Show and instead use a own created winform as dialog this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar app (vb.net) where win1 calls win2 & win2 displays win3 and it works as you would like but wins 2 & 3 are both modal.  I don't know if that is why it works or not.  Perhaps that is an option for you?

Comment: But when there is no modal dialog in win3 it should be easy to switch to win1 och win2. So these can´t be set at modal.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
var winform2 = new Winform2();
winform2.Show(winform1);
```

Then winform2 will always be shown above winform1, but it won't be modal. May be this can help you.

Comment: This will try to open winform1 as a modal dialog for winform2, this is not what I want.

Comment: @SnowJim: No, this will open winform2 with (the already open) winform1 as owner. It means that winform2 will always be shown in front of winform1. When winform1 is minimized, winform2 will automatically be hidden until winform1 is restored. Moreover, when winform1 is closed, winform2 will automatically be closed as well.